# Make maven's surefire show stacktrace in console

Tags: maven, unit-testing, stack-trace, maven-surefire-plugin

I'd like to see the stacktrace of unit tests in the console. Does surefire support this?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use the following command to see the stack trace on console instead of report files in the  target/surefire-reports folder:

```
mvn -Dsurefire.useFile=false test
```

Comment: This only have logger output into console, but stacktraces still goes to surefire-reports

Comment: The answer using **trimStackTrace** is better!

Answer (score 276):

A related problem that I found is that surefire in recent versions apparently sets trimStackTrace to true by default (rendering most stack trace in failed tests useless), which is quite inconvenient.

Setting `-DtrimStackTrace=false` or defining

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

solved this.

Comment: Yep. Not only does Maven print pages of pointless diarrhea, but it hides what you actually need to see.

Comment: I created an issue about this wrong default https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1457. Please comment it to help its reopening.

Comment: @RédaHousniAlaoui Seems they moved it to another issue for JUnit 5: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1432 Just voted there.

Comment: I set both 'trinStackTrace' and 'useFile' to false... and still I'm just getting no stack traces for my test failures :-(

Comment: @Kris do you means stack traces has lots of line, the output show ... 26  more?

Comment: Default is now `trimStackTrace=false` in 3.0.0-M6.  However, we're still using 3.0.0-M5 ... `:--)`

Answer (score 29):

To extend the answer given before, you also can configure this behavior in your `pom.xml`:

```
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <configuration>
        <useFile>false</useFile>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ...
```